# How to set width and height for VideoPlayer in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I am using VideoPlayer to play an .mp4 video that is uploaded to my website.
I set the height and width and it works as I expect in Android, but in Flutter Web the width doesn't match the width of the container.

```
   Container(//      
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      height: 130,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
         color: Colors.black12, border: 
         Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
      child: SizedBox(width: double.infinity,
          child: ClipRRect(borderRadius:  
          BorderRadius.circular(8), 
          child: VideoPlayer(HomePage._controller1)
      )
     )
    ),
```

[image: status on web is like this]

I need some trick to make my video full width or  fit to it's parent.

Comment: It might not look better with fixed height and like to have always max Width on web.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using AspectRation for this.

```dart
/// use on parent widget, the place you like to get width, 
/// most likely I prefer on Scaffold's body 
/// and then removing subtract the padding from maxWidth 
LayoutBuilder( 
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    final width = constraints.maxWidth;

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: width < 600 ? 1.5 : 2.0, //try different ration based on your preference
      child: Container( //your VideoPlayer
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but apparently it depends on container height, if I un-set height it will be full width, but i need to change scale with fixed height,